# How to avoid the graph object's edges in a Plot3D look so fat?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

I have a graph `graph0` inside a plot as below:-

```
data = {{9, 9, 900}, {8, 1, 800}, {3, 2, 800}, {3, 2, 600}};
graph0 = NearestNeighborGraph[data, 2];
plot0 = 
  Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, All}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Texture[Red]];
Show[{plot0, graph0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

As you can see, the edges of the graph are so fat. If I amended the 3rd column of `data` from 900, 800, 800, 600 to 9, 8, 8, 8, then the edges will look normal as below:-

[image]

How can I keep the edges look normal even when the 3rd column are still 900, 800, 800, 600?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use, for example,

```
graph0 = NearestNeighborGraph[data, 2,
   VertexShapeFunction -> (Point[#1] &),
   VertexStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
   EdgeShapeFunction -> (Line[#1] &),
   EdgeStyle -> Thickness[0.01]
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. So that means if `graph0` is given by the others but not generated by me, I should use `SetProperty` to set value for all of these 4 options?

Comment: That sound like a good way!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
graph0 =
  NearestNeighborGraph[data, 2,
    EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
    EdgeStyle -> {Thick, Black},
    VertexSize -> Tiny];
plot0 =
  Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, All}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Texture[Red]];
Show[{plot0, graph0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: plot]